# Twisted, gevent eventlet - When would I use them

Tags: python, twisted, gevent, eventlet

Under what circumstances would something like eventlet/gevent be better than twisted? Twisted seems like the most used, but eventlet/gevent must have some advantages...
I'm not looking for an answer to a specific scenario, just generalities.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an issue of aesthetic preference, I think.

First of all, eventlet can actually use Twisted for networking, so in a sense, it's not an either-or question, it's a this-is-built-on-top-of-that question.

Personally, I don't see the need for libraries like gevent or eventlet, especially since the advent of the `@inlineCallbacks` decorator in Twisted, which already write code which sorta looks like it's blocking.

But, if you have a large library of code which already uses threads, and you want to port it to be event-driven, something like eventlet can save you some typing, since you don't need to insert '`yield`'s everywhere..  Some people, like the guys behind the EVE online game, think that code written in this style is just better for some things, such as AI code.